# Ajax header basic auth: request timeout not working on wp8

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am currently writing a remote for the VLC Media Player. I use the http-webinterface to connect to and control the server. Since version 2.1.0 VLC requires a password to be set. This itself is not a problem. I solved it with the following Ajax-Request

```
checkConnection = function(id, folder){
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://' + data.ip + ":" + data.port + '/requests/status.xml',
    headers: {
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + data.authorization
    },
    timeout: 3000,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        //Yeah do stuff
        }       
    },
    error: function(data){
        //Ohh, do stuff
    }
  });
};
```

If I connect to the VLC http-interface using my computer there is this standard popup asking me for the username and a password. My problem right now is, that if the token in data.authorization is wrong, the app (using the phone) crashes. If tested with Ripple (using Chrome) the mentioned popup shows, but the timeout works and my error handling kicks in. This is not the case on my Windows Phone - here my app hangs (as mentioned). I do suspect, that since it is a webview WP tries to display the popup, but fails. Then again, the timeout should kick in?

Did any of you have the same problem and if so how did you solve it?

Comment: Alright. I tried to debug it, but the app just crashes and wont do other stuff. It wont react at all. So I'm still working on it and hope anyone can help me - can't belive I'm the only one who had a problem like that :)

Comment: Try run the app with 'Break when exception is thrown' option - Ctrl+Alt+E from VS

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. But that doesn't change anything. The App still hangs :( and I don't see any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved. It was quite easy and just required writing a plugin in C#. I'll attached the code for anybody who might encounter the same problem.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;

namespace WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands
{
    public class BasicAuth : BaseCommand
    {
        //Create timer to control timeout
        DispatcherTimer timeoutTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    public BasicAuth(){
        timeoutTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        timeoutTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timeout);
        timeoutTimer.Start();
    }

    public void get(string options)
    {
        //Parse data that gets passed into the plugin
        string[] passedData = JSON.JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(options);

        string ip = passedData[0];
        string port = passedData[1];
        string username = passedData[2];
        string password = passedData[3];            

        try
        {
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
            string credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials);
            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            string authorization = String.Concat("Basic ", base64);
            webClient.Headers["Authorization"] = authorization;
            string url = //your url here
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Data);
            DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, ""));
            timeoutTimer.Stop();
        }
    }

    void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try{
            DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, e.Result)); //e.Result will fail if the server couldn't be contacted
        } catch{
            DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, ""));
        }
    }

    private void timeout(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webClient.CancelAsync(); //Cancel Async download
        timeoutTimer.Stop(); //Stop timer from beeing executed again
    }
}
}
```

Here is the bit you would call from your JavaScript:

```
cordova.exec(connectionSuccess, connectionError, "BasicAuth", "get", [data]);
```