# AngularJS Interceptor Never Catches 401 Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-service, ionic-framework

I'm using Angular v1.2.20 with the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com). I have seen many articles and posts about how to handle 401 errors from the server by using an interceptor and pushing it into the `$httpProvider.interceptors` array.

For some reason, 401 responses never get caught by the `repsonseError` function in my interceptor. The promise I am expecting to reject never rejects and my app just seems to hang (`loading:hide` from below never gets called). I can see from my web debugging proxy that a 401 is definitely returned from the server.

My interceptor:

```
.factory('interceptorService', function($rootScope, $q, Session, AuthorizationHeader) {
  var interceptorService = {
    request: function(config) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show');
      config.headers['Authentication-Key'] = Session.key();
      config.headers['Authentication-Timestamp'] = (new Date().toJSON());
      config.headers['Authentication-Account'] = Session.accountName();
      if(typeof config.headers['Authorization'] === 'undefined') {
        config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Custom-HMAC-SHA512 ' + AuthorizationHeader.buildHashed(config, Session.key());
      }
      return config || $q.when(config);
    },

    response: function(response) {
      if(response.status === 401) {
        console.log('401');
      }
      $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },

    requestError: function(config) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
      return $q.reject(config);
    },

    responseError: function(response) {
      console.log('response error');
      $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };

  return interceptorService;
})
```

I can confirm that the interceptor is working as, when I get a 403 back from the server, I can see 'response error' in my console log. Please also note that this happens regardless of HTTP verb used. It's happening with HEAD calls and DELETE calls.

Any help is very much appreciated.

### ## Edit

It appears that this problem is caused by cordova/phonegap not being able to handle the `www-authenticate` header in the 401 response as referenced [in this blog post](http://me.eekay.nl/index.php/2014/cordovaphonegap-and-the-missing-callback-for-401-unauthorized/).

If anyone has any ideas on how best to handle that, I'm all ears.

Comment: but tried to put console.log('something');  outside of if ? and look if respnose  function entered In general

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan I tried that. I get no log from the `response` function. Any other thoughts? Also the `loading:hide` never gets triggered.

Comment: is server sending 401 status?

Comment: @charlietfl I am using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) as a web debugging proxy and seeing 401 from the server. So, yes, I believe I am getting 401 back. Again, 403s and 500s hit the response error function. Just not 401 for some reason.

Comment: are you sure what you pushed your interceptor in $httpProvider.interceptors  ?

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan  `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('interceptorService');` is in my `config`. I believe it is there because my `loading:show` and `loading:hide` work for all other requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the WWW-Authenticate header from the response before it gets back to your app. That's what fixed it for me.

[handle 401 unauthorized error on windows Phone with Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897271/handle-401-unauthorized-error-on-windows-phone-with-phonegap/25941869#25941869)

Edit: The implementation that was used at my work was done at our F5 (load balancer) since that's where our Basic Authentication occurs.

Here's something I whipped up, that has NOT been tested. You could possibly place this in the Application_EndRequest method in Global.asax.cs file:

```
    if (context.Response.Headers.Contains("WWW-Authenticate"))
        context.Response.Headers.Remove("WWW-Authenticate");
```

Comment: this sounds great; can you please update your example with how to remove that header from the service? The response and responseError properties never get hit in the interceptor. How do I remove it from the service side? I would love to accept this answer