# My authentication token interceptor does not intercept request/response of fresh route

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, jwt, express-jwt

I am trying to implement jwt authentication for my nodejs, express and angularjs app. So far I have generated the token, and stored it in my `localStorage`. According to [this](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) tutorial, I have implemented the `authInterceptor` in angular factory as follows:

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($window.localStorage.myToken) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.localStorage.myToken;

      }
      return config;
    },
    response: function (response) {
      if (response.status === "401") {
        $window.location.replace('/dash');
      }
      return response || $q.when(response);
    }
  };
});
```

I have pushed the interceptor in config file as follows:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
```

So far I have sent the credentials to server, generated the token and stored it in `localStorage`.

So as long as I have not deleted the token from localStorage, and the token has not expired, I think it is supposed to persist. If I make requests from within the loaded page using the background ajax call of angularjs, the authentication header is set as it is supposed to.

`Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiYSIsInR5cGUiOiJzYWxlcyIsImlhdCI6MTQyMjI2MDExMCwiZXhwIjoxNDIyMjc4MTEwfQ.Iv6W-Tc8Qm4FGclzmgbtjvWFz_tyDwEvrFmMmucONpY`

However neither my request nor my response is intercepted when I navigate to a new route. For eg, I have my '/sales' route. But when I navigate to sales route from address bar, neither the request authentication header is set by the interceptor, thus returning authorization error 401 from server, which is not intercepted either; hence not redirecting to `/dash`.

Here is link of the error, and the headers of GET request to unauthorized route '/sales':
[image: request and response header at 401 error]

Comment: Hint: Have you ever looked at responseError?

Comment: `NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - http://localhost:9090/sales`

Comment: My apologies, I should have been clearer. In the sense of: responseError: function(rejection) {
 if(rejection.status == 401){
        //do something with path
  } }

Comment: is this supposed to go inside interceptor or inside the controller?

Comment: It is part of the interceptor just like the response and request are. I use responseError to detect if my status was a 401 and then redirect the user to a login page in my case.

Comment: nope. somehow, the interceptor is not intercepting the request or the response. I dont knw why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have understood so far is, normally before javascript frontend frameworks how the http request were served was:

- We type a url in address bar.
- The browser sends the request.
- The server gets the request.
- serves the necessary html, js and css files.
- browser renders it.

But as the recent shift to various javascript frontend frameworks and use of RESTful api.s has begun, the request needs to have authorization header. Thus in many of the single page web apps with javascript frameworks like angularjs,

- the initial request for '/' router is sent
- the server serves the web application to the browser
- all the further routing in the web application is done within the front end application, hence the "#" after the url.
- Requests are made by the application to fetch, update, delete or post from the application through angular js.

So when a request is made from angular application, it is intercepted from angular application and intercepted by your interceptor. However when a url is entered from the address bar, the browser sends request directly to server, because at that point of the request, the browser has not loaded the angular web application.

What I did was you set html5mode to false and put a `#` before your route.

like `localhost/#/some-route` and do the routing from your route provider. When there is `#` before your route, the request for `/` goes to server, the application loads, and then the request is sent through the application. Now from this `some-route`, make some controller make request to the desired server endpoint, which will be intercepted by interceptor.

Comment: I seem to be having an problem very similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481206/using-passport-for-authentication-of-api-endpoints

Answer (score 2):

Is your backend sending the `WWW-Authenticate` header along with the 401 status? If so, and it contains `Basic`, the browser will catch the response and show the credentials popup before Angular could catch it.

Try either removing or altering it.

References:

- [AngularJS Interceptor Never Catches 401 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730637/angularjs-interceptor-never-catches-401-error)
- http://olefriis.blogspot.com/2014/01/http-basic-authentication-in-angularjs.html
- [Preventing HTTP Basic Auth Dialog using AngularJS Interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130308/preventing-http-basic-auth-dialog-using-angularjs-interceptors)

Comment: thank you... it sure does makes sense... but trying to implement it... u gave me atleast some head start...

Comment: i could not fine the www-authenticate header. I am using [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) to create token, [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) to intercept the authorization header at server and as described, angular Interceptor to intercept the response at client side.